# Asterisks Re-registration timer

Tags: asterisk, pptp, freepbx

I have a freepbx box running freepbx 12.0.43 and asterisk Asterisk 11.15.0. I have two panasonic KX-UT133 ip phones at a remote location connected to the main office (where the freepbx box is )  through pptp vpn. Everything works excellently until there is a minor internet hiccup or the router at the main office reboots for any reason. As soon as internet is restored, the pptp vpn is restored with it as the vpn is set to "always on" but not the phones. The phones re-registers after approximately 30mins  which leads me to believe that there is a re-registration timer buried somewhere in asterisks. The only way to get the phones to register immediately is to get someone at the remote location to restart them.I have checked the phone's web GUI THOROUGHLY but didnt see any mention of re-registration time. Does anyone know where such a timer is in asterisk and or freepbx so that i can lower it to 5 or 10 mins for the 2 phones?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way: you can change time inside phone(almost always have such posibility for hardware, sometimes for software)

In asterisk you can set

```
defaultexpiry=
maxexpiry =
```

Unfortanly both params are global param

Also you can enable nat ping on phone. If ping lost it will trigger re-register.

So best options will be do changes on phone's config, not asterisk.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I have triple-checked the phone's web GUI but didn't see anything about re-registration timer. i have more than one hundred other phones sitting in same LAN as freepbx box, it doesnt sound like a good idea to have all of them re-registering every 5mins.

Comment: Phone usualy have "register interval" in advanved options. Unfortanly no way answer your question more deeply using data provided.

Comment: Thanks @arheops. Like i said, i have checked the phone's web GUI thoroughly and didn't see anything like that. What data do u need ?? I can  forward port 80 to one of these phones if u re willing to take a look yourself.